# Can not see all columns of data table because browser is not showing horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have implement a data table using `bootstrap` with approximately 38 columns. All columns are being shown in browser of `eclipse`, `eclipse` is showing horizontal scroll bar in browser. But in `chrome` or any other browser it is not showing horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Please provide some code (html, css)

Comment: Without any code its almost impossible to guess what is going wrong. That being said if there is no horizontal scrollbar then you might have `overflow: hidden` set on a parent element. You will need to remove that for the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. We have found the answer and changed the script in jsp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `script` with this now it is working:

```
<script>
        $( function () {

            /* Data Table Initialization */
            var equipmentDataTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
                                            "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sClass": "text-center", "aTargets": [ 0,25 ] },
                                                             { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 25 ] }],
                                            "sScrollX": '100%'
                                     });

            /* Add row functionality of the table */
            $('#addEquipment').click( function() {

                equipmentDataTable.fnAddData( [ '1',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentDesc" data-type="text">N/A</a>',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentModel" data-type="text">N/A</a>',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentLaborSubGroup" data-type="select">Others</a>',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentHorsepower" data-type="text">N/A</a>',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentMonthlyPrice" data-type="text">0</a>',
                                            '0',
                                            '0',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentMaintenanceBase" data-type="text">0</a>',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentMaintenanceIndex" data-type="text">0.12</a>',
                                            '0',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentFuelBase" data-type="text">0</a>',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentFuel" data-type="text">1.0</a>',
                                            '0',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentLubricantBase" data-type="text">0</a>',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentLubricant" data-type="text">1.0</a>',
                                            '0',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentLaborRate" data-type="select">0</a>',
                                            '0',
                                            '0',
                                            '0',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentCapabilityOutput" data-type="text">0</a>',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentCapabilityUnit" data-type="text">N/A</a>',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentCapabilityPeriod" data-type="select">N/A</a>',
                                            '<a href="#" class="equipmentRemarks" data-type="text">N/A</a>',
                                            '<input type="checkbox" class="deleteEquipmentCheckBox">' ] );      
            });

            /* Delete row functionality of the table */
            $('#deleteEquipment').click( function() {
                $('input.deleteEquipmentCheckBox:checked').each( function () {
                    equipmentDataTable.fnDeleteRow( $(this).closest('tr')[0], false );
                } );
                equipmentDataTable.fnDraw();
            });
        });
        </script>
```